# Dynamic Array TextView is not displaying

Tags: android, kotlin, dynamic, view

I am trying to display multiple textviews in an array. It should first show a hint to enter value and on click it allows you to enter value, once done, the screen shows the value with another field below to enter the next value

Header ----      Total

Header ----      Total

Header ----      Total

But the below code is not displaying the new textviews. The textview is clickable and should appear one below the other based on size of the array. Not sure why this code is not working. I using RelativeLayout for displaying the dynamic views

```
val itemTitle = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(size)
        val itemValue = arrayOfNulls<TextView>(size)

        for (k in invoiceItems!!.indices) {

            val rec = invoiceItems!![k].itemTitle
            Log.i("Re-ceived Item title", rec)

            //Item Name Display on Invoice Activity

            val layoutParams: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ) // or wrap_content
            layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START)

            itemTitle[k] = TextView(this)
            itemTitle[k]!!.hint = "Enter Item Title"
            itemTitle[k]!!.textSize = 16f
            itemTitle[k]!!.layoutParams = layoutParams
            itemTitle[k]!!.isClickable = true
            itemTitle[k]!!.isFocusable = true
            itemTitle[k]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.txtcolor))
            invoiceItemsLayout.addView(itemTitle[k])
            itemTitle[k]!!.text = invoiceItems!![k].itemTitle
            val value = invoiceItems!![k].itemTitle
            Log.i("Item title value", value)



            //Total Item Value
            itemValue[k] = TextView(this)
            val layoutParams2: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            ) // or wrap_content
            layoutParams2.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END)
            if(k != 0){
                layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, (k-1))
            }
            itemValue[k]!!.text = "00.00"
            itemValue[k]!!.textSize = 16f
            itemValue[k]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.txtcolor))
            itemValue[k]!!.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 10)
            itemValue[k]!!.layoutParams = layoutParams2
            invoiceItemsLayout.addView(itemValue[k], layoutParams2)
            itemValue[k]!!.text = invoiceItems!![k].itemTotal.toString()

            if(k == size) {
                //New Item Title field
                itemTitle[k + 1] = TextView(this)
                val layoutParams: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ) // or wrap_content
                layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_START)
                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.hint = "Enter Item Title"
                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.textSize = 16f
                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.isClickable = true
                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.isFocusable = true
                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.txtcolor))
                invoiceItemsLayout.addView(itemTitle[k], layoutParams)

                //New item value field
                itemValue[k + 1] = TextView(this)
                val layoutParams2: RelativeLayout.LayoutParams = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                ) // or wrap_content
                layoutParams2.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
                layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END)
                itemValue[k + 1]!!.text = "00.00"
                itemValue[k + 1]!!.textSize = 16f
                itemValue[k + 1]!!.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.txtcolor))
                itemValue[k + 1]!!.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 10)
                itemValue[k + 1]!!.layoutParams = layoutParams2
                invoiceItemsLayout.addView(itemValue[k], layoutParams2)

                itemTitle[k + 1]!!.setOnClickListener {
                    updateInvoiceValues()
                    val intent = Intent(this, EditBillingItem::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("invoiceItem", invoiceItems as Serializable)
                    intent.putExtra("index", k + 1)
                    intent.putExtra("invoiceEdit", invoiceEdit as Serializable)
                    this.startActivity(intent)
                }

            }
            itemTitle[k]!!.setOnClickListener {

                updateInvoiceValues()
                val intent = Intent(this, EditBillingItem::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("invoiceItem", invoiceItems as Serializable)
                intent.putExtra("index", k)
                intent.putExtra("invoiceEdit", invoiceEdit as Serializable)
                this.startActivity(intent)
            }
            subTotal += invoiceItems!![k].itemTotal
            val taxValue = invoiceItems!![k].itemRate!!
            taxrate += (subTotal * taxValue)
        }
        invoiceSubValue.text = subTotal.toString()
        total = subTotal + taxrate
        invoiceTaxValue.text = taxrate.toString()
        invoiceTotalValue.text = total.toString()

    }
```

Comment: Try to temporarily use a LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout. In this way you can be sure Views are well created and well added to its parent ViewGroup. If the Views became visible in a LinearLayout, then the problem is their position/Roles/Margins/etc...

Comment: agree but since I am not inflating a view I am forced to use relativelayout, have realised that views are visible but overlapping. Dont know how to get one after the other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set TextView's ID and use addRule(BELOW, textview_id) instead of "(k-1)" which means nothing for the Rule. Rules uses "IdRes" and not simple Integers.

Example (Java):

```
itemValue[k] = new TextView(this);
itemValue[k].setId(View.generateViewId());
...
layoutParams2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, itemValue[k].getId());
...
invoiceItemsLayout.addView(itemValue[k], layoutParams2);
```

View.generateViewId() secures that the generated ID will be UNIQUE and not already used by some other Views.